# Drawing nested squares in Python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have a function `cup()` which should draw a three sided square resembling a measuring cup. While I think I wrote that code correctly, the function `cups()`, which calls it, does not work properly, as the pictures show. Can anyone see what my problem is? I tried changing the length by which it goes forward, but that didn't do anything. It keeps ending at the top side of the first square. Thanks for any help.

```
def cup(t,sideLength):
    for i in range(3):
        t.forward(sideLength)
        t.left(90)
        t.pu()
        t.forward(sideLength)
        t.left(90)
        t.pd()

def cups(t,initial,incr,reps): #needs work
    '''calls the function cup repeatedly to draw a set of measuring cups of 
    increasing size.'''
    for i in range(reps):
        cup(t,initial)
        t.pu()
        t.right(90)
        t.fd(incr)
        t.lt(90)
        t.pd()
        initial += incr

import turtle
s = turtle.Screen()
t = turtle.Turtle()
cups(t, 50, 30, 4)
```

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VW0O5.png)

[Correct code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmfaz.png)

Answer (score 0):

There were a few problems with the code.

function cup was over-complicated - always test the basic one first - there are two ways to do it, one with a range and one without.  I did the one without for simplicity.

Then the problem is thinking about where the turtle ends up and how to increase the step - you were increasing but to go evenly from the center container, you have to think about the increase being distributed - half to the top and half to the bottom.

```
import turtle

t = turtle.Turtle()

def cup(sideLength):
    """Draws one cup and returns to origin"""
    t.pd()
    t.forward(sideLength)
    t.left(90)
    #t.pu()
    t.forward(sideLength)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(sideLength)
    t.pu()
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(sideLength)

def cups(initial,incr,reps): #needs work
    '''calls the function cup repeatedly to draw a set of measuring cups of increasing size.'''
    start = initial
    for i in range(reps):
        cup(start)
        t.pu()  
        t.forward(incr/2)
        t.left(90)
        start += incr

#cup(50)
cups(50, 30, 4)
```

Follow the flow of the code and add comments to make sure you understand what each line is doing.

Comment: No problem cdlane.  I hope you can understand what the code is doing- more lines of code that are readable and easy to understand when beginning with a new language can be better than short code that is harder to read imho :) check out regular expressions (regex) if you want one-line code answers. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your `cup()` function has the correct steps but unfortunately puts some inside the loop that should come after the loop:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def cup(turtle, sideLength):
    for _ in range(3):
        turtle.forward(sideLength)
        turtle.left(90)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(sideLength)

def cups(turtle, initial, incr, reps):
    '''
    Calls the function cup() repeatedly to draw
    set of measuring cups of increasing size.
    '''

    for length in range(0, incr * reps, incr):
        cup(turtle, initial + length)
        turtle.forward(incr / 2)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.pendown()

screen = Screen()
tortoise = Turtle()

cups(tortoise, 50, 30, 4)

screen.exitonclick()
```

That plus a little adjustment of how much you move between cups solves your problem.  I've illustrated a different way to use `for ... in range(...)` in the `cups()` function.  I've also made `cup()` slightly aware of what `cups()` is up to so that it avoids extra turns, drawing the figure in a smooth motion.